# Word Choice: Cleanup vs organization

Tags: american-english

I organized (I didn't clean it) my boss's office the other day and I was wondering what would be the best thing to write on the invoice to charge him for my services.

Since I didn't really "clean" his office, meaning I didn't have a wet cloth in my hands and started wiping everything down and moping the floor I'm now caught in uncertainty for what to say. Should I put it down as:

Office organization?
Or
Office cleanup?

Isn't cleaning up and organizing the same thing? If it is, does it make organization and cleanup the same too? Please help.

- English as a second language problems.

Answer (score 1):

You would say, for example “I organized your office” or “I organized the paperwork on your desk”.  Be specific about the task you performed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used "Tidy up" which is more in line with what you did.  Or "decluttering" in the case that the office was cluttered as in piles of things out of place.

Something that is tidy is something neat and organized.

What you see in the picture is clutter. A mess. You can tidy it up or declutter.

[image]

But I think office organizing sounds better for an invoice.